# How to add default json dashboard template while deploying using yaml

Tags: kubernetes, grafana

I am trying to get default Grafana dashboard and admin username/password on deploy.

I tried creating `values.yaml` but doesn't seem like its working

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: grafana
  namespace: monitoring
  labels:
    grafana_dashboard: "1"
data:
  dashboard-k8.json: | (3)
    ${indent(4, data)}
```

Is there any better working way to do this? and I used same method for default username and password for grafana.

I am working on a maintenance project so its not new installation of Grafana. But, the requirement is to have default dashboard set with new admin username and password when the service is deployed.

Comment: Where do you want to get the `Grafana dashboard`? Is it local? How the `dashboard-k8.json` should be look like?

Comment: It is deployed on kube cluster and dashboard -k8 can be any json dashboard in this case.

Answer (score 2):

As per the grafana docker [documentation](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/setup-grafana/configure-docker/#configure-grafana-with-docker-secrets), any config in the `grafana.ini` file can be set at runtime using environment variables of the format `GF_<SectionName>_<KeyName>__FILE`, which represent paths to files containing the actual value. So we can use the environment variables `GF_SECURITY_ADMIN_USER__FILE`, `GF_SECURITY_ADMIN_PASSWORD__FILE` and `GF_DASHBOARDS_DEFAULT_HOME_DASHBOARD_PATH__FILE`, to set the admin username, password and the dashboard that is opened at launch.

According to the instructions in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63518460/grafana-import-dashboard-as-part-of-docker-compose/74995091#74995091), we can use a dashboard provider of type `file` to import dashboards from files.

Using both these techniques together, I think I was able to get what you wanted.

**Steps performed:**

- Created a secret that contains the admin password. At runtime, the password gets mounted into the grafana container at `/etc/secrets/admin_password` and environment variable `GF_SECURITY_ADMIN_PASSWORD__FILE` gets set to `/etc/secrets/admin_password`
- Created a config map that contains the dashboard provider config which gets mounted as `/etc/grafana/provisioning/dashboards/main.yaml`
- Created another config map that contains the admin user and default dashboard path. These values are exposed to the container as files `/etc/config/admin_user` and `/etc/config/default_home_dashboard_path`, with those file paths set to the `GF_SECURITY_ADMIN_PASSWORD__FILE` and `GF_DASHBOARDS_DEFAULT_HOME_DASHBOARD_PATH__FILE` environment variables
- Created another config map which contains the JSON for the default dashboard. The JSON file gets mounted as `/var/lib/grafana/dashboards/test-dashboard.json`, with the text `/var/lib/grafana/dashboards/test-dashboard.json` exposed as `/etc/config/default_home_dashboard_path`(set in the previous step)

**Config map for the dashboard JSON:**

```yaml
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app: grafana
  name: grafana-dashboards
data:
  test-dashboard.json: |-
    {
      "annotations": {
        "list": [
      ...truncated...
    }
```

**Other config maps and deployment spec:**

```yaml
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app: grafana
  name: grafana-secrets
type: Opaque
stringData:
  admin_password: testpwd
  
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app: grafana
  name: grafana-dashboard-provider
data:
  dashboard.yml: |-
    ---
    apiVersion: 1

    providers:
      - name: "Dashboard provider"
        orgId: 1
        type: file
        disableDeletion: false
        updateIntervalSeconds: 10
        allowUiUpdates: false
        options:
          path: /var/lib/grafana/dashboards
          foldersFromFilesStructure: true
          
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app: grafana
  name: grafana-config
data:
  admin_user: testuser
  default_home_dashboard_path: /var/lib/grafana/dashboards/test-dashboard.json        

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app: grafana
  name: grafana
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: grafana
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: grafana
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: secret-volume
          secret:
            secretName: grafana-secrets
            items:
              - key: admin_password
                path: admin_password
        - name: dashboard-provider-volume
          configMap:
            name: grafana-dashboard-provider
            items:
              - key: dashboard.yml
                path: main.yaml
        - name: dashboards-volume
          configMap:
            name: grafana-dashboards
            items:
              - key: test-dashboard.json
                path: test-dashboard.json
        - name: config-volume
          configMap:
            name: grafana-config
            items:
              - key: admin_user
                path: admin_user
              - key: default_home_dashboard_path
                path: default_home_dashboard_path          
      containers:
        - name: grafana
          image: grafana/grafana-oss:9.5.1
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3000
          volumeMounts:
            - name: secret-volume
              mountPath: /etc/secrets
            - name: dashboard-provider-volume
              mountPath: /etc/grafana/provisioning/dashboards
            - name: dashboards-volume
              mountPath: /var/lib/grafana/dashboards
            - name: config-volume
              mountPath: /etc/config
          env:
            - name: GF_SECURITY_ADMIN_PASSWORD__FILE
              value: /etc/secrets/admin_password
            - name: GF_SECURITY_ADMIN_USER__FILE
              value: /etc/config/admin_user
            - name: GF_DASHBOARDS_DEFAULT_HOME_DASHBOARD_PATH__FILE
              value: /etc/config/default_home_dashboard_path
```

The complete config files can be found on [github](https://github.com/devatherock/random-demo/commit/fd868fa7f488fcb77091a0202499da8684c905df)

Comment: This i ve tried but while deploying with ansible, the json inside yaml is not working. I am trying with values.yaml

Comment: I haven't used ansible before. When you say not working, is the grafana container not starting? Or is the dashboard not showing up after the container starts successfully? If the container has started successfully in kubernetes, you can use a command like `kubectl exec <pod-name> -- cat /var/lib/grafana/dashboards/test-dashboard.json` to view the content of the json file inside the container and verify that it is correct.

Comment: Grafana is working but the dashboards are missing